# 0MQ - JZMQ unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, linux, zeromq, jzmq

I've installed 0MQ on a VM running CentOS and I have a C-based application happily working with it. However, I'm unable to get the Java application to work via JZMQ bindings. Here's the error I get:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -jar AidApps.jar receive localhost:9007
Starting the receiver application.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/lib/libjzmq.so.0.0.0: libzmq.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:34)
at com.ijet.Receiver.main(Receiver.java:9)
at com.ijet.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

I don't get any errors during installation of either 0MQ or JZMQ. I tried copying all libraries into /usr/local/lib but that didn't solve anything. Any ideas? This works on my Mac (so I know the JAR works), but not on the Linux box.

Comment: run `ldd /usr/local/lib/libjzmq.so.0.0.0` and give us the output

Comment: Here's the output

    `ldd /usr/local/lib/libjzmq.so.0.0.0`  
    `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa1f31000)`  
    `libzmq.so.1 => not found`  
    `libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4f7a17c000)`  
    `libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f79ef8000)`  
    `libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f79b68000)`  
    `libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4f79951000)`  
    `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033ca600000)`

Comment: does `libzmq.so.1` exist? Try `file libzmq.so.1`, is it a 64-bit ELF?

Comment: When I run that command I get the following: `libzmq.so.1: symbolic link to `libzmq.so.1.0.0'`

Comment: Does `libzmq.so.1.0.0` exist ?  Is the path in `/etc/ld.so.conf` ? How about `file libzmq.so.1.0.0` ?   Does `ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib` help?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, your suggestion worked! I added a zmq.conf file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` which contains the path to `/usr/local/lib`, then I ran `ldconfig` and now I'm able to run the JAR without throwing an exception. Thanks a bunch for all your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because ld.so cannot resolve your `libzmq.so.1.0.0`.

Add the path `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.config` and run `ldconfig` to rebuild the cache.

Answer (score 10):

Steps to fix this problem (credit goes to to J16-SDiZ):

1) `cp /root/zeromq-2.1.11/src/.libs/*.* /usr/local/lib`
2) `nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zmq.conf`
3)  Add line `/usr/local/lib` and save
4) `ldconfig`
5) Verify by running `ldconfig -v | grep zmq`
6) Run the JAR `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/ -jar AidApps.jar receive localhost:9007`

Note that the -Djava.library.path still needs to be specified, point it to the jzmq.jar file.